# Have HTML5 canvas text rotated when a button in click

Tags: html, text, canvas

I'm just playing around with HTML5 canvas and text. I've text on the canvas and I want to be able to rotate it a few degrees on the click of a button. How is this possible?

Comment: search for css rotation

Answer (score 0):

```
context.save();
context.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
context.rotate(-Math.PI/8);
context.fillText("I'm rotated a little");
context.restore();
```